# How to access a workflow's history outcome in MS Sharepoint?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, workflow

i m currently using Microsoft Visual Studio to create a webpart for MS Sharepoint. May i ask how do i access the Libraries/List where a workflow is implemented to get the Workflow History and Outcome when it is completed?

Currently i have codes to access the individual fields, which is to get the list's different column:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://win7:8000/RIDepartment/");
SPWeb oweb = site.OpenWeb();
SPList tasklist = oweb.Lists["Innovation workflow list"];
```

then to get the first item, i use tasklist[0].However i cant get the workflow histroy from there, thanks.

Melvin

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the various workflow tutorials https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+2010+workflow+tutorial+c%23

You will need to get the workflow on your list item via `SPListItem.Workflows`. Once you get your correct `SPWorkflow` from the returned `SPWorkflowCollection` you can get the related history list and task list via the `HistoryListId` and `TaskListId` properties ([see the SPWorkflow doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflow_members.aspx)).

So basically something like this should work:

```
SPListItem item = tasklist[0];
SPWorkflow workflow = item.Workflows[0];
SPList historyList = workflow.HistoryList;
SPList taskList = workflow.TaskList;
```

*However this code pretty much sucks so just use it as a starting point, also you shouldn't use [0] but get the workflow you really want (e.g. by knowing its name).*